# OpenJDK 17 heap memory issue

Tags: java, heap-memory, java-17

my code :

```
public class Memory {
// Dummy Entity representing usual data objects
private static class Entity {
    public String name;
    public String detail;
    public Double amount;
    public Integer age;
}

// Linked list offers table inserts and helps illustrating the issue by using multiple
// references per entry
public static java.util.LinkedList<Entity> entities = new java.util.LinkedList<>();

// This threshold should be 2 times Xmn. It ensures the loop stops before a full GC happens.
private static final int MB = 1024 * 1024;
private static final int THRESHOLD = 100 * MB;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Total Memory (in bytes): " + Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory());
    System.out.println("Free Memory (in bytes): " + Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
    System.out.println("Max Memory (in bytes): " + Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory());

    while (true) {
        appendEntitiesToDataStructure();
        terminateBeforeFullGCorOOMEcanHappen();
    }
}

private static void appendEntitiesToDataStructure() {
    entities.add(new Entity());
}

private static void terminateBeforeFullGCorOOMEcanHappen() {
    if (Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() < THRESHOLD) {
        System.out.println("Elements created and added to LinkedList: " + entities.size());
        System.exit(0);
    }
}}
```

launch :

```
java -Xms${i}g -Xmx${i}g -Xmn50m memory.java >> output.txt
```

Idea : I want to know the behavior of JVM heap size when it evolves.

Heap size : from 1 to 100 GB

GC tested : g1c, zgc, pgc

Result : with g1c and pgc there is regression from 32GB -> I can store less data in my object as heap size increases.

Schema : X : size of my object ; Y : heap size

I don't know how to explain this behavior -> any idea ?

[image: java g1gc]
[image: java gpc]
[image: java zgc]

Comment: IIRC 32GB heap is when the JVM turns off [compressed oops](https://wiki.openjdk.org/display/HotSpot/CompressedOops) (simply speaking: 32bit references in a 64bit JVM). It's likely this is the cause for what you see.

Comment: I don't sea this behavior with ZGC because there is no compressed oops ?

Comment: That's what your graphs suggest and a quick Google search confirm that this at least *was* true a while ago (with JDK 15). I suspect it's simply still true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to this article: https://www.baeldung.com/jvm-compressed-oops

First, let's find out what an oop is:

> The HotSpot JVM uses a data structure called [oops](https://www.baeldung.com/java-memory-layout) or Ordinary Object Pointers to represent objects. These oops are equivalent to native C pointers. **The [instanceOops](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk15/blob/master/src/hotspot/share/oops/instanceOop.hpp) are a special kind of oop that represents the object instances in Java**. Moreover, the JVM also supports a handful of other oops that are kept in the [OpenJDK source tree](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src/share/vm/oops/).

Furthermore

[image]

A very neat feature is the compressing of oops to 32 bits:

> As it turns out, the JVM can avoid wasting memory by compressing the object pointers or oops, so we can have the best of both worlds: **allowing more than 4 GB of heap space with 32-bit references in 64-bit machines!**

Finally:

> To enable oop compression, we can use the -XX:+UseCompressedOops tuning flag. The oop compression is the default behavior from Java 7 onwards whenever the maximum heap size is less than 32 GB. **When the maximum heap size is more than 32 GB, the JVM will automatically switch off the oop compression**. So memory utilization beyond a 32 Gb heap size needs to be managed differently.

So, the answer to your question is: you simply passed beyond the threshold of 32 GB as the maximum heap size.

**Proof**

Look at your graphs and see that the behavior we are speaking about happens at the level of 32 GB.